# Hashing from a public key to a bitcoin address in php

Tags: php, hash, public-key-encryption, bitcoin

I am trying to follow the instructions required to turn a 65 byte public key into a bitcoin address using php.  The instructions are quite explicit.  Can anyone help me with the practicality of doing that in php?

Instructions are

1 - Take the corresponding public key generated with it (65 bytes, 1 byte 0x04, 32 bytes corresponding to X coordinate, 32 bytes corresponding to Y coordinate)

0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6

2 - Perform SHA-256 hashing on the public key

600FFE422B4E00731A59557A5CCA46CC183944191006324A447BDB2D98D4B408

3 - Perform RIPEMD-160 hashing on the result of SHA-256

010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEE

4 - Add version byte in front of RIPEMD-160 hash (0x00 for Main Network)

00010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEE

5 - Perform SHA-256 hash on the extended RIPEMD-160 result

445C7A8007A93D8733188288BB320A8FE2DEBD2AE1B47F0F50BC10BAE845C094

6 - Perform SHA-256 hash on the result of the previous SHA-256 hash

D61967F63C7DD183914A4AE452C9F6AD5D462CE3D277798075B107615C1A8A30

7 - Take the first 4 bytes of the second SHA-256 hash. This is the address checksum

D61967F6

8 - Add the 4 checksum bytes from point 7 at the end of extended RIPEMD-160 hash from point 4. This is the 25-byte binary Bitcoin Address.

00010966776006953D5567439E5E39F86A0D273BEED61967F6

9 - Convert the result from a byte string into a base58 string using Base58Check encoding. This is the most commonly used Bitcoin Address format

16UwLL9Risc3QfPqBUvKofHmBQ7wMtjvM

My first attempt is

```
// step 1

$publickey='0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6';
$step1=$publickey;

echo "step1 ".$publickey."<br>";

// step 2

$step2=hash("sha256",$step1);
echo "step2 ".$step2."<br>";

// step 3

$step3=hash('ripemd160',$step2);
echo "step3 ".$step3."<br>";

// step 4

$step4="00".$step3;
echo "step4 ".$step4."<br>";

// step 5

$step5=hash("sha256",$step4);
echo "step5 ".$step5."<br>";

// step 6

$step6=hash("sha256",$step5);
echo "step6 ".$step6."<br>";

// step 7

$checksum=substr($step6,0,8);
echo "step7 ".$checksum."<br>";

// step 8

$step8=$step4.$checksum;
echo "step8 ".$step8."<br>";

//step 9

$step9=base58_encode($step8);
echo "step9 ".$step9."<br><br>";
```

This fails at the first step.  Any help appreciated.

This is the output

```
step1 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6
step2 32511e82d56dcea68eb774094e25bab0f8bdd9bc1eca1ceeda38c7a43aceddce
step3 7528c664cdc34c5ce809778eb688d32f89a538c0
step4 007528c664cdc34c5ce809778eb688d32f89a538c0
step5 86e76f4ff0bf0387339ac70a552e0fed615f7def34cc4809df1429e243f6c1fa
step6 b885b7225b370e7ff27ee0afb4f89b52b8675d5dc342d63de3abe7535f86cadb
step7 b885b722
step8 007528c664cdc34c5ce809778eb688d32f89a538c0b885b722
step9 1
```

Base58 function is

```
function base58_encode($input)
{
    $alphabet =     '123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $base_count = strval(strlen($alphabet));
    $encoded = '';
    while (floatval($input) >= floatval($base_count))
    {
        $div = bcdiv($input, $base_count);
        $mod = bcmod($input, $base_count);
        $encoded = substr($alphabet, intval($mod), 1) . $encoded;
        $input = $div;
    }
    if (floatval($input) > 0)
    {
        $encoded = substr($alphabet, intval($input), 1) . $encoded;
    }
    return($encoded);
}
```

Comment: If it fails it does so with an error message. What is that message?

Comment: @Mike W - add the output - the fail is that it is not what is expected

Comment: Variable names `$publickey` and `$publicKey` are not equivalent.

Comment: @Sammitch - yes - even that does not work!

Comment: Also: `$step8=$step4+$checksum;` should be `$step8=$step4.$checksum;` if I'm interpreting the instructions properly.

Comment: @anthonyc bluntly: if it "doesn't work" then you're doing it wrong. Check your variable names again. Also, turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and it will throw warnings about the variables not existing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution below with thanks to Sammitch for spotting syntax and providing the base conversions.

```
<?php

// step 1

$publickey='0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6';

$step1=hexStringToByteString($publickey);

echo "step1 ".$publickey."<br>";

// step 2

$step2=hash("sha256",$step1);
echo "step2 ".$step2."<br>";

// step 3

$step3=hash('ripemd160',hexStringToByteString($step2));
echo "step3 ".$step3."<br>";

// step 4

$step4="00".$step3;
echo "step4 ".$step4."<br>";

// step 5

$step5=hash("sha256",hexStringToByteString($step4));
echo "step5 ".$step5."<br>";

// step 6

$step6=hash("sha256",hexStringToByteString($step5));
echo "step6 ".$step6."<br>";

// step 7

$checksum=substr($step6,0,8);
echo "step7 ".$checksum."<br>";

// step 8

$step8=$step4.$checksum;
echo "step8 ".$step8."<br>";

// step 9
// base conversion is from hex to base58 via decimal. 
// Leading hex zero converts to 1 in base58 but it is dropped
// in the intermediate decimal stage.  Simply added back manually.

$step9="1".bc_base58_encode(bc_hexdec($step8));
echo "step9 ".$step9."<br><br>";

?>
```

hash requires a byte string not a hex string.  hexStringToByteString is

```
function hexStringToByteString($hexString){
    $len=strlen($hexString);

    $byteString="";
    for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i=$i+2){
        $charnum=hexdec(substr($hexString,$i,2));
        $byteString.=chr($charnum);
    }

return $byteString;
}
```

base conversion (thanks to Sammitch - amended to use Bitcoin base58)

```
// BCmath version for huge numbers
function bc_arb_encode($num, $basestr) {
    if( ! function_exists('bcadd') ) {
        Throw new Exception('You need the BCmath extension.');
    }

    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $rep = '';

    while( true ){
        if( strlen($num) < 2 ) {
            if( intval($num) <= 0 ) {
                break;
            }
        }
        $rem = bcmod($num, $base);
        $rep = $basestr[intval($rem)] . $rep;
        $num = bcdiv(bcsub($num, $rem), $base);
    }
    return $rep;
}

function bc_arb_decode($num, $basestr) {
    if( ! function_exists('bcadd') ) {
        Throw new Exception('You need the BCmath extension.');
    }

    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $dec = '0';

    $num_arr = str_split((string)$num);
    $cnt = strlen($num);
    for($i=0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
        $pos = strpos($basestr, $num_arr[$i]);
        if( $pos === false ) {
            Throw new Exception(sprintf('Unknown character %s at offset %d', $num_arr[$i], $i));
        }
        $dec = bcadd(bcmul($dec, $base), $pos);
    }
    return $dec;
}


// base 58 alias
function bc_base58_encode($num) {   
    return bc_arb_encode($num, '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz');
}
function bc_base58_decode($num) {
    return bc_arb_decode($num, '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz');
}

//hexdec with BCmath
function bc_hexdec($num) {
    return bc_arb_decode(strtolower($num), '0123456789abcdef');
}
function bc_dechex($num) {
    return bc_arb_encode($num, '0123456789abcdef');
}
```

final output

```
step1 0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6
step2 600ffe422b4e00731a59557a5cca46cc183944191006324a447bdb2d98d4b408
step3 010966776006953d5567439e5e39f86a0d273bee
step4 00010966776006953d5567439e5e39f86a0d273bee
step5 445c7a8007a93d8733188288bb320a8fe2debd2ae1b47f0f50bc10bae845c094
step6 d61967f63c7dd183914a4ae452c9f6ad5d462ce3d277798075b107615c1a8a30
step7 d61967f6
step8 00010966776006953d5567439e5e39f86a0d273beed61967f6
step9 16UwLL9Risc3QfPqBUvKofHmBQ7wMtjvM
```

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at your variable names. $publickey is not the same as $publicKey - note capitalisation.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems are as follow:

1. Variable names $publickey and $publicKey are not equivalent.
2. `$checksum=substr($step6,0,4);` should be `$checksum=substr($step6,0,8);` because you need *two* hex chars to represent one byte.
3. `$step8=$step4+$checksum;` should be `$step8=$step4.$checksum;`

Also, I don't know where your `base58_encode()` function comes from, but I hope it uses BCmath, because the number represented by `00ba084d3f143f2896809d3f1d7dffed472b39d8de7a39cf51` [step 8's result] is too large for PHP to handle internally.

### edit

I'm super bored at work today, here's my conversion code with bonus BCmath for ginormous [say, 58-digit?] numbers.

```
<?php

// original arbitrary encode function
function arb_encode($num, $basestr) {
    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $rep = '';

    while($num > 0) {
        $rem = $num % $base;
        $rep = $basestr[$rem] . $rep;
        $num = ($num - $rem) / $base;
    }
    return $rep;
}

function arb_decode($num, $basestr) {
    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $dec = 0;

    $num_arr = str_split((string)$num);
    $cnt = strlen($num);
    for($i=0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
        $pos = strpos($basestr, $num_arr[$i]);
        if( $pos === false ) {
            Throw new Exception(sprintf('Unknown character %s at offset %d', $num_arr[$i], $i));
        }
        $dec = ($dec * $base) + $pos;
    }
    return $dec;
}

// BCmath version for huge numbers
function bc_arb_encode($num, $basestr) {
    if( ! function_exists('bcadd') ) {
        Throw new Exception('You need the BCmath extension.');
    }

    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $rep = '';

    while( true ){
        if( strlen($num) < 2 ) {
            if( intval($num) <= 0 ) { break; }
        }
        $rem = bcmod($num, $base);
        $rep = $basestr[intval($rem)] . $rep;
        $num = bcdiv(bcsub($num, $rem), $base);
    }
    return $rep;
}

function bc_arb_decode($num, $basestr) {
    if( ! function_exists('bcadd') ) {
        Throw new Exception('You need the BCmath extension.');
    }

    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $dec = '0';

    $num_arr = str_split((string)$num);
    $cnt = strlen($num);
    for($i=0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
        $pos = strpos($basestr, $num_arr[$i]);
        if( $pos === false ) {
            Throw new Exception(sprintf('Unknown character %s at offset %d', $num_arr[$i], $i));
        }
        $dec = bcadd(bcmul($dec, $base), $pos);
    }
    return $dec;
}


// base 58 alias
function bc_base58_encode($num) {
    return bc_arb_encode($num, '123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ');
}
function bc_base58_decode($num) {
    return bc_arb_decode($num, '123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ');
}

//hexdec with BCmath
function bc_hexdec($num) {
    return bc_arb_decode(strtolower($num), '0123456789abcdef');
}
function bc_dechex($num) {
    return bc_arb_encode($num, '0123456789abcdef');
}

// example
$orig    = '00ba084d3f143f2896809d3f1d7dffed472b39d8de7a39cf51';
$bten    = bc_hexdec($orig);
$base58  = bc_base58_encode($bten);
$backten = bc_base58_decode($base58);
$back    = bc_dechex($backten);
echo "Orig: " . $orig . "\n";
echo "bten: " . $bten . "\n";
echo "58:   " . $base58 . "\n";
echo "ag10: " . $backten . "\n";
echo "Back:   " . $back  . "\n";
```

### edit2

Don't use `base_convert()` for numbers this large, it appears to be unreliable. I was writing the necessary `bc_arb_decode()` counterparts and found that the input and output were differing using `base_convert()` versus `arb_convert($num, '0123456789abcdef');` and after comparing the results with [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ei4ll2bgmsr) it seems that PHP is incorrectly converting the number.

```
Hex:           00ba084d3f143f2896809d3f1d7dffed472b39d8de7a39cf51
PHP's decode:  4561501878697786606686086062428080084446806606846864824262
Mine:          4561501878697784703577561586669353227270827349968709865297
Wolfram Alpha: 4561501878697784703577561586669353227270827349968709865297
```

You can see that PHP is *way* off. [1.9E42 aka 1.9 quintillion septillion] I've updated my code to include the `arb_decode()` functions which appear to do things *correctly*.

Comment: thanks (must get some new glasses!).  Fixed and new output posted.  Still not what is expected.

Comment: @anthonyc see my edit. I think you're using the same base58 function I found. [it's crap] I wrote my own and it's less crap, but it still can't handle how large the number is, 4.5615018786978E+57. That's a FIFTY EIGHT DIGIT NUMBER.

Comment: I added the base58 code above. Found somewhere on this forum.  I will give yours a crack but I wonder why I am not getting the first hash right?  Should I be transforming the hex string into a 65 byte array char array?

Comment: @anthonyc that I can't say. I don't know if the hashing functions are supposed to operate on alphanumeric hex strings, or binary hex strings. However, I have noticed that `base_convert()` is also broken for numbers this big, see my edits.

Comment: Very neat!  It turns out I do need to convert the hex string to a byte string for the hashing.  Also bitcoin uses a particular base58 where the capitals precede the lower case letters. Finally, 00 hex maps to 1 base58 but taking it via decimal drops the leading zero added in step 4 - so I just add it back in step 9.  Full solution below.  Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Very Important!**

**Replace this:** '123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'

**With this:** '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'

Using the wrong code here would cause Bitcoin transactions to fail or worse, cause coins to disappear to a phantom wallet where they can never be retrieved.

I am not a developer but I confirmed the correction. The Base58 symbol chart is here, https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding

I checked my work here  http://brainwallet.org/

Enter the passphrase: "test address" without the quotes.

The public key is then: 047969a753f71135d4c792f384e546cd508514024b4ee40d12a014019b77d1b292763dfb8a108cf7a7119f80ca4a06e81b92464f5d8a7544d52cd2e641023a96d7

Your address result : **1gBG1mbVtyNTgGZhggJ21A6mnjbNtqPCSr**

My result: **1Gch1MBvUZotGhzHGGj21b6MNKBoURpdsS**

brainwallet.org result:  **1Gch1MBvUZotGhzHGGj21b6MNKBoURpdsS**

I hope this saves someone from a time consuming or costly error.

Comment: The answer already has this substitution and is correct.  Please note also that the answer explicitly states that you must amend the base58 to the Bitcoin base58.  For the sake of clarity you may want to amend your 'this is wrong' comment.

Comment: anthonyc, thank you very much for the code you placed here. I searched the web for this explanation. It was a HUGE help in my understanding of these concepts! But it's still wrong. Many visitors (such as myself) don't have your understanding of this code and won't catch, or understand, the little comment "amended to use Bitcoin base58". For us beginners the difference isn't easily apparent. I wanted to save others the hours of searching that it took me to find the solution.

Comment: You are welcome.  I am glad it was useful to you. You are right that it is important to change the base system.  The code marked as the answer (below) contains that correction and works. The code in the question was my first attempt and was not working - which is why I posted!